# Keycloak User Storage SPI - Why getUserById invoked 4 times after getUserByUsername from UserLookupProvider interface

Tags: java, keycloak

I am upgrading my keycloak 3.4 to 9.0.2. I previously wrote a User Storage SPI as per guide lines and it was still working great in old version.

I ran into some problems After upgrading Keycloak core and keycloak server SPI in my User Storage SPI pom file when I tried to login with updated SPI jar deployed in new keycloak server.

Here is the updated Dependencies

[image: dependencies]

In Previous Version The only method invoked to verify user is getUserByUsername. Here is the screenshot from 3.4.3 version

[image: only getUserByUsername invoked in 3.4.3]

But in New Version getUserById invoked after getUserByUsername and it invoked 4 times. I am not understanding why. Somehow I was able to workaround this and its working but I am thinking why its got invoked 4 time.  check this screenshot.

[image: getUserById invoked 4 times]

These are 4 database calls. Which is not an efficient way to fetch same user from database. If its by design or due to some bug then suggest me how can I make sure the 2nd calls do not hit database instead it use the loaded object. I am not using JPA, its simple JDBC calls to database. IF any other information required then you can ask me.

Note : I am using Password grant flow by giving username and password to get token.

Comment: How were you able to make it work. I am facing the same issue in Keycloak 11. Earlier on Keycloak 8 it was working fine.

Comment: @Mubashar Did you mange to find the reason?